# how to surround a Java statement with if-else or try-catch constructs?

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

Is there a functionality where Visual Studio will automate, to an extent the process of:

> Manually surround a piece of code with a Java construct (if-else,
>   try-catch, etc.) is time-consuming process. For a user, it means to
>   jump to the beginning of the code, position the cursor right, type the
>   code, jump to the end, position cursor, write a code. It certainly can
>   be automated. Surround With feature should allow to surround
>   statements easily.

Example screenshot:

[image: throw exception]

I'm coming from [Netbeans](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/hi/promoD/surroundWith.html), where this is an option.

Version info:

```
Version: 1.41.1
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T15:04:31.999Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.18.0-25-generic snap
```

Comment: The OS is not relevant.  This is functionality of the IDE and the IDE alone.

Comment: oh, okay.  there was something about being sure to post the version, and there seems to be a difference in the ide tags, no?

Comment: Difference between what?  (I deleted the irrelevant [linux] tag ... if that is what you mean.)

Comment: the visual-studio tag indicates to specify version, etc:  please mention your exact version, update and edition.

Comment: I see.  But 1) it doesn't mention OS, and 2) this doesn't necessarily mean you should indicate this via the tags.  I think it means to indicate this in the text of your question.   When you tag a question [linux] it is supposed to mean that the question is **about** linux.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the supported "refactorings and code actions" are described in:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing#_refactoring-and-code-actions.

When I looked at this, I could not see a code action for enclosing a statement in a try / catch.  However, at the bottom it says:

> *"The list of Code Actions supported by VS Code keeps growing and only listed the most popular ones above."*.

So ... my suggestion would be to look in the menu in your Visual Studio / VS Code.  Also, watch the release notes and the issue tracker for the Redhat project that is developing the Java plugin.

---

**UPDATE** - In fact, here is the issue:

- https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/300

So it looks like there is a code action to do this.  Merged in September 2017.

Comment: thanks.  I'm not understanding why I don't see this option then.

Comment: Hmmm ... don't know.  Perhaps they quietly removed it for some reason?  Anyhow, it is either there or it is not there, and if it is not there you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a different plug-in, or something.  I'm going to keep poking around, but this and lack of fixing imports seems kinda basic.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: (This would be one of the reasons that I prefer to stick with Eclipse.  But nothing is perfect :-) )

Comment: I really like the "feel" of visual code.  I was just using it for powershell, but it has a nifty terminal for git and gradle and is very "lightweight" in several regards.   perhaps too light...